# What is the ruby way to add hash to an existing array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a large data set with a fixed amount of categories.  I have been originally storing everything in an array of hashes.  Works great, but considering the size of the data and the redundancy of the categories, it is not efficient.

I am now using a hash of different types/categories and storing arrays of hashes inside each category.

Right now my current method to add data is deleting the `:type` key of each hash before adding it to the type array.  Everything is working.  Nevertheless, I am sure there is a more streamlined 'Ruby way' of doing this:

```
# Very large data set with redundant types.
gigantic_array = [
  { type: 'a', organization: 'acme inc', president: 'bugs bunny' },
  { type: 'a', organization: 'looney toons', president: 'donald' },
  { type: 'b', organization: 'facebook', president: 'mark' },
  { type: 'b', organization: 'myspace', president: 'whoknows' },
  { type: 'c', organization: 'walmart', president: 'wall' }
  # multiply length by ~1000
]

# Still gigantic, but more efficient.
# Stores each type as symbol.
# Each type is an array of hashes.
more_efficient_hash = {
  type: {
    a: [
      { organization: 'acme inc', president: 'bugs bunny' },
      { organization: 'looney toons', president: 'donald' }
    ],

    b: [
      { organization: 'facebook', president: 'mark' },
      { organization: 'myspace', president: 'whoknows' }
    ],

    c: [
      { organization: 'walmart', president: 'wall' }
      # etc....
    ]
  }
}

hash_to_add = { type: 'c', organization: 'target', president: 'sharp' }

# Adds hash to array of types inside the gigantic more_efficient_hash.
# Is there a better way?
more_efficient_hash[:type][hash_to_add[:type].to_sym].push(hash_to_add.delete(:type))
```

Comment: how is the second hash more efficient?

Comment: @TheCha͢mp it is more normal?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking

Comment: I think the biggest improvement you can achieve is to encapsulate the data structure into a class (and also the single organizations). Then, the user code does not have to deal with the internal structure and you can change it when necessary. Apart from that, I think your structure is efficient for inserting (depending on if/how you want to look it up).

Comment: Btw. the outer hash with just one key `:type' seems to be pointless.

Comment: @TheCha͢mp more normal as in the data is more 'normalized'.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [undur_gongor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969032/what-is-the-ruby-way-to-add-hash-to-an-existing-array-of-hashes#comment53764212_32969032) that some small data classes would be helpful, and also that the `:type` key in your result doesn't add any value.

For your initial conversion from `gigantic_array`, you can do it easily with `group_by`. Note that `Hash#delete` returns the value of the deleted key, not the hash, so I'm not convinced your last line is working the way you want.

```
> more_efficient_hash = gigantic_array.group_by {|item| item.delete(:type).to_sym}
{
  a: [
    {:organization=>"acme inc", :president=>"bugs bunny"},
    {:organization=>"looney toons", :president=>"donald"}
  ],
  b: [
    {:organization=>"facebook", :president=>"mark"},
    {:organization=>"myspace", :president=>"whoknows"}
  ],
  c: [
    {:organization=>"walmart", :president=>"wall"}
  ]
}
```

From that point, your last line is pretty clean. Because `delete` is destructive, we can shorten it a bit.

```
> more_efficient_hash[hash_to_add.delete(:type).to_sym] << hash_to_add
# ...
  c: [
    {:organization=>"walmart", :president=>"wall"},
    {:organization=>"target", :president=>"sharp"}
  ]
```